# How prove $((x-y)(y-z)(z-x))^2\le 2((x^2-y^2)^2+(y^2-z^2)^2+(z^2-x^2)^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

let $x,y,z>0$, and such $$x^2+y^2+z^2=x^2y^2+y^2z^2+x^2z^2$$
show that
$$((x-y)(y-z)(z-x))^2\le 2((x^2-y^2)^2+(y^2-z^2)^2+(z^2-x^2)^2)$$

My try: let
$$x-y=a,y-z=b,z-x=c\Longrightarrow a+b+c=0$$
then we only prove
$$2[a(a+b)^2+b(b+c)^2+c(c+a)^2]\ge a^2b^2c^2$$
or
$$2(ac^2+ba^2+cb^2)\ge a^2b^2c^2$$

then I can't

Comment: I haven't given it a real try yet, but did you try to replace x-y, y-z, z-x with a, b,c? Then, you can also replace those other trerms. please note that, for example:$$(x^2-y^2)^2=[(x-y)(x+y)]^2=[a(a+b)]^2$$

Comment: @china math, this is good prob, pls edit your question by adding more relevant info to it, so it will come at the top of the question list and we will get solution

Comment: I am sorry. I have just seen that you actually had this idea, before I posted here. I am sorry. I would be interesting to give some more details about the problem. Such as..where did you find it? I personally need a hint to tackle this.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, we can prove the following sharper inequality holds

$$2\big[(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)\big]^{2}\leq (x^{2}-y^{2})^{2}+(y^{2}-z^{2})^{2}+(z^{2}-x^{2})^{2}$$

Without loss of generality, assume that $x \geq y \geq z > 0,$ then
\begin{aligned} 2\big[(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)\big]^{2} \ & \leq 2(x-y)^2x^2y^2 \leq 2(x-y)^2(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2) \\ & =2(x-y)^2(x^2+y^2+z^2) \leq 2(x-y)^2(x^2+y^2+2xy) \\ & =2(x^2-y^2)^2 \leq (x^2-y^2)^2+(y^2-z^2)^2+(z^2-x^2)^2.\end{aligned}